# Slow queries with preparedStatement but not with executeQuery

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm having a weird problem with an Grails application accessing data. Going deeper I've isolated the problem to a plain java8 small application using PreparedStatement.executeQuery vs Statement.executeQuery.

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
                  
    // executes in milliseconds                  
    directSql   = "select top(10) * from vdocuments where codcli = 'CCCC' and             serial = 'SSSS' ORDER BY otherField DESC;";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(directSql);


    // More than 10 minutes
    sqlPrepared = "select top(10) * from vdocuments where codCli = ? and  serial = ? ORDER BY otherField DESC;";
    PreparedStatement pStatement = con.prepareStatement( sqlPrepared );
    pStatement.setString(1, "CCCC");
    pStatement.setString(2, "SSSS");
    rsPrepared = pStatement.executeQuery();
```

Same query.

Data comes from a view on SqlServer (2008, I think, have no access right now) from a table with more than 15 Million records. There are indexes for all needed fields and the same query (the first one) executed from console runs also quite fast.

If I execute the slow PreparedStatement query without the ORDER clause it also runs fast.

It looks clear to me that for any cause the database it's not using indexes and make a full scan when using preparedStatement, but maybe I'm wrong so I'm open to any idea.

I thought maybe the driver (sqlserver official latest and jtds has been tested) was holding the data waiting for any kind of EOF from connection but I've checked with tcpdump on my side and no data is received.

I can't find why this is happening so any idea will be welcomed.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: For performance problems, the first thing I suggest is reviewing the execution plan.

Comment: I'm going to try it but, why should be different in both cases?. And worst, how do I do it for a preparedStatement?.  I cannot execute from java an _EXPLAIN PLAN... _  as far as I know.

Thank you!

Comment: The plans might be different because of data type mismatch or due to parameter sniffing. The execution plan will reveal this but a common problem is that Unicode string parameters are compared to a varchar column which prevents indexes from being used efficiently. Or it may be due to parameter sniffing where a cached plan is reused that is suboptimal for the current parameter values.

Comment: You'll need your DBA to help get the plans. They should be able to extract those from the query cache on the database server. It's a lot easier if you have a development/test environment where you have the permissions to do that on your own, run traces, etc. When you get the plans, upload to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the links to your question.

Comment: Thank you @danguzman for you suggestion (and the page, I didn't knew). 

I was looking at DB plans with some experienced database people (not a real DBA on our team nor the customer) and it becomes obvious that SQL was using different indexes than expected for plans in some cases.  We  were unable to find why and need to go deeper on knowledge but looks like this may be the more precise approach to our problem:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/

Thank you vey much!

Comment: The `OPTIMIZE FOR` query hint is useful to provide a stable plan in cases where a query is executed frequently and parameter sniffing is a problem. If the query isn't executed often `OPTION RECOMPILE` might be a better choice since that should provide the best plan for the provided values, albeit at the cost of compilation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found a solution, at least in for my case. I got it here http://mehmoodbluffs.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/hibernate-queries-are-slow-sql-servers.html .  Telling (driver? sqlServer?) not to send parameters as Unicode have resolved the problem.

Current connection string it's now:

```
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;databaseName=myDataBase;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false";
```

And now both direct queries and preparedStatements runs at millisecond speed.

Thank you @DanGuzman for your suggestions!